# Bug in C# OpenFileDialog if two fullstops in filename

Tags: c#, filter, openfiledialog

I have an OpenFileDialog with the filter set to *.wav. However, when I execute the OpenFileDialog it also shows other files that **includes** .wav but the true extension is not .wav but e.g. png. Why is that and how can I avoid this?

Right now I take care of it when loading the file(s) for processing but I would like to avoid getting them in the OpenFileDialog list in the first place. Is this a bug in the control or is it me?

Background: I had by accident renamed a picture file to TheFile.wav.png - stupid, true, but these kind of things happens also for other users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow; are you trying to show _only_ the .wav files or _only_ the .png files?  Or are you trying to show both?

Comment: Better option is to validate after user selects the file. You maynot have noticed it will list all the files when you press `*` and enter

Comment: Cannot reproduce your scenario. Could you show how do you set the Filter property of your OpenFileDialog?

Comment: Are you sure you specified the filter in the right format?
Is it in this format: `WAV File (*.wav)|*.wav` ?

Comment: I only want to show the files with the - true - .wav extension and not those files that are named e.g. TheFileName.wav.png. I do validate the actual files when loading them but I would like not to get "false" extensions in the net. I believe I have set the right filter: openFileDialog1.Filter = "Wav files|*.wav";

Comment: try `"*.wav?"` but this will match `*.wave` too

Comment: `"Because this method checks against file names with both the 8.3 file name format and the long file name format, a search pattern similar to "*1*.txt" may return unexpected file names. For example, using a search pattern of "*1*.txt" returns "longfilename.txt" because the equivalent 8.3 file name format is "LONGFI~1.TXT"."` That is from the Directory.GetFiles documentation but the reason why you cant do this is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to set the file type in the dialog:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "wav files (*.wav)|*.wav";
dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";  // You may not need this.
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)  // Or this; I was just being thorough.
{
   //  Your code can go here.
}
```

Just make sure that when using the `.Filter` property, you follow the pattern I have above, or else it won't work.  Also, as was mentioned above, you may want to do some validation after the user selects something.

Comment: Sorry Brian, no luck either with that filter :-(

Comment: Could it be related to the Windows settings? I have extensions visible.

Comment: @BoOZ2M - I doubt it.  I suggest that you parse the file extensions while you are processing them and use a `foreach` loop to filter on.

Comment: Well, problem solved. It surfaces if Filename = "*.wav". If blank then the OFD behaves as it should. However, don't know why. Thanks for stimulating the troubleshooting.

Comment: You are most welcome; and I am glad that you solved your problem!